# ImageIcon won't display in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I'v been trying to use Image Icon for my Pokemon game by showing an image of each start when you are picking them. However, the image doesn't show up when I run my program yet it doesn't throw an errors. The image is in a folder named images in the src folder. I'v been learning Swing by myself pretty well, but this problem stumped me.

```
public ImageIcon f = new ImageIcon("images/bulbasaur.png"); //declared in the bulbasaur class

Bulbasaur bulb = new Bulbasaur(1, "Bulbasaur", 5);    // declared in the main class
final JLabel test = new JLabel();
test.setIcon(bulb.f);
test.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: This isn’t really a Swing problem.  It’s problem with understanding what the current directory is what a relative filename is.  Each process has a current directory associated with it.  Any filename which does not start with ‘/’ or a Windows drive letter followed by ‘:\’ is a relative filename, which means it is resolved with the current directory as the base.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Java may be unable to find the image with the path given I would try changing your first line

```
public ImageIcon f = new ImageIcon(Bulbasaur.class.getResource("images/bulbasaur.png"));
```